# Extracting strings between mutiple lines matching a pattern using python

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a file [samplefile.txt] like this -

```
dummy line 1
dummy line 2
create_list animal -list     
  tiger
create_list bird -list        
  crow
dummy line 3
create_list car -list        
  ford/mustang
dummy line 4
dummy line 5
create_list truck
  -list ford/F150
create_list human -list {
  jack
  john}
```

I wanted to get an output like this - 
`['tiger', 'crow', 'ford/mustang', 'ford/F150']`

Code I am using -

```
import re

def extractListItems(File):
    f = open(File,"r")
    content = f.read()

    list_items = []

    for m in re.finditer(r'(?:\bcreate_list+\s+\S+\s+-list+\s*)((?:\b\S+\b(?:\s*))+)(?:\n)', content):
            list_items.extend(re.split(r'\s+', m.group(1).strip()))

    print (list_items)
    f.close()

extractListItems("samplefile.txt")
```

What is the modification I need to make to get my required output?

Edit - Changed by file content and required output.

Comment: Can you have more items in a list, or only one? Do all item lines begin with two spaces, and all dummy lines with "dummy"? If the answers to the last two questions are 'yes', then it's way easier to do it by iteration over the file, instead of using re.

Comment: I can have have more items in a list. But the dummy lines don't have dummy. It is a big file around 100k lines.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the words you want to match are always indented.

```
import re
regex = r"^\s+(\S.*)"

test_str = ("dummy line 1\n"
    "dummy line 2\n"
    "create_list animal -list     \n"
    "  tiger\n"
    "create_list bird -list        \n"
    "  crow\n"
    "dummy line 3\n"
    "create_list car -list        \n"
    "  ford/mustang\n"
    "dummy line 4\n"
    "dummy line 5")

match = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(match)
```

### Output

`['tiger', 'crow', 'ford/mustang']`

Comment: `r"^\s+(.+)"` is better re-written as `r"^\s+(\S.*)"` since `\s` and `.` can match the same symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Changed my answer according to ist

Answer (score 0):

if Your content always start with spaces then try this

```
import re

def extractListItems(File):
    f = open(File,"r")
    content = f.read().splitlines()
    pattern=lambda data:len(re.findall(r"^\s+",data))
    lst=[c.strip() for c in content if pattern(c)>0]
    print(lst)
    f.close()

extractListItems("samplefile.txt")
```

output

```
['tiger', 'crow', 'ford/mustang']
```

OR

```
 pattern=lambda data:re.findall(r"^[\s].*",data)
 lst=[val[0].strip() for val in map(pattern,content) if val]
```

Result

```
 ['tiger', 'crow', 'ford/mustang']
```